# How to set limit_req on a certain folders?

Tags: nginx

How can I set limit_req on all folders except on a "uploads and public" for example.

What I've tried:

```
    location / {
        root /var/www/html/public;
                            if ( $uri !~ ^/(uploads|public) ) {
                                limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay;
                            }
...
```

error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "limit_req" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my.conf:20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those cases where you're not allowed to use a directive within `if`.

You can either use an intermediate variable:

```
set $burst 75;
if ( $uri !~ ^/(uploads|public) ) {
    set $burst 5;
}
limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay;
```

Or have a separate `location`.

Some more details for future thoughts have been covered in an answer to a more detailed question: [Magento and nginx - multiwebsite configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693457/magento-and-nginx-multiwebsite-configuration/20751659#20751659).